# Window.Location.reload() versus AJAX

Tags: ajax, gwt

On my GWT app (which is in maintenance), I'd like to refresh a list of people once's one of them has been deleted.

I'm looking into how to send the right AJAX request to refresh the list of followers, but I'm curious if it's acceptable to call `Window.Location.reload()`?

Calling reload seems lazy and overkill since only a part of the page should update - AJAX.

Please advise me on whether `Window.Location.reload()` is OK, and why/why not.

Comment: You'd have to weigh the benefits of only fetching the updated data in an AJAX call and cleanly updating the interface for the user vs the simpler but more visually obvious and slightly more network taxing page refresh.

Comment: Users don't like their page refreshing. They can't always follow what happened and it's an abrupt visual change.  It also hinders the usability of the application since they have to wait for the page to finish loading before they may continue interacting with it.

Comment: @TheZ: Your point about updating vs refreshing a UI is valid: Especially for complex state changes, and for highly flexible UIs, it can sometimes be a lot easier to simply rebuild the whole thing instead of updating it. But with AJAX, you can (if you want) just as easily remove all widgets, then update your client-side data model, and create new widgets. That's not harder than doing effectively the same thing with a server side UI framework. Using this simplistic AJAX + UI rebuild approach, you can still save most of the page-reload tax (even if this approach leaves room for improvement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never reload a page if you only need to remove a single line of text. Depending on which widget is used to display the list of names in your case, it would most likely take just one line of code in GWT to remove it. This is as much code as necessary to reload the page, but it offers a better user experience and consumes much less resources.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. My gut told me that what I was doing was easy, but wrong. Conceptually, I would expect that I'd have to ask my Group Model to make a request to the server to reload my Group page. How would you conceptually explain what I need to do?

Comment: There must be a handler attached to a widget on a page which triggers deletion of a name. In a typical implementation this handler will tell the server (through RPC or RequestBuilder) to delete a name in a datastore. The same handler can remove the name from this widget, or it can be done in onSuccess() method of the AsyncCallback. The details depend on what you use for client-server communication, your design pattern (MVP, etc.), which widget is used to display names and which widget is used to trigger the deletion of a name.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.reload()` causes the entire page to reload.  AJAX is intended to allow updating content on the page without having to navigate away from it (via reload or otherwise).